# Is there an ANSI/ISO SQL syntax to obtain the current time?

Tags: sql

I would like to get a DB's current time, using Standard SQL.
The result must either be in UTC or come with timezone information.
Is that possible? If yes, how?

---

Apparently, there's CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, which is ANSI SQL, but is there an ANSI SQL syntax to retrieve just that? Some DBMS support `select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, others require `select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from DUAL`. Any way to do this DBMS-independent?

Comment: Could you provide some more information which platform you use, i.e.  Oracle, SQL server etc?

Comment: Please provide DB engine provider. There is no one ANSI standard

Comment: No.  There's not a standard SQL Syntax to get the current time across **ALL** RDBMS platforms.  That doesn't mean you couldn't create a standard UDF and utilize the supported functions for each RDBMS you encounter though.

Comment: When it comes to date/time, many products are far from standard compliant. I guess you can find a few standard compliant products, but still you'll have to deal with a number of non-compliant products.

Comment: Trying to write totally DBMS-independent code is bound to be an unattainable quest.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

<strike>There is no standard function to do this (as far as I know).
Each vendor implemented their own functions to handle date and time, including retrieving the current time.</strike>

See @jarlh's answer on this.

**Possible solution** (given you have control over the database):

You can create a view containing one record using (or a function proxying) the vendor specific function and use that as a source in your application.

For example (SQL Server)

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.[DateTime] AS
SELECT
  SYSUTCDATETIME() AS UTCDateTime
;
```

or in (MySQL)

```
CREATE VIEW DateTime AS
SELECT
  UTC_TIMESTAMP as UTCDateTime
;
```

Answer (score 2):

The **ANSI/ISO SQL standard** has `CURRENT_TIME` to get time *with* timezone information, and `LOCALTIME` to get time *without* timezone information.

However, many products have their own functions instead.

Comment: Yeah, I also just found CURRENT_TIME/CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. How do I get only that value? In Oracle I'd do 'select CURRENT_TIME from dual', but that's again a DBMS-specific concept.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use SQL server:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), GETUTCDATE(), 108)
```

Comment: No, I specifically asked for "Standard SQL". I'd like to have something that works on all (*) DBMS.
(* well, as many as possible, anyway)

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI SQL way of doing this is to use the `VALUES` statement. This is similar to the `SELECT` statement, in that it returns a result set. But it doesn't reference any table. It's the standard way of doing something like what Oracle's `DUAL` pseudo-table is used for.

Here's a demo using MySQL 8.0:

```
mysql> VALUES ROW(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
+---------------------+
| column_0            |
+---------------------+
| 2021-11-22 14:56:58 |
+---------------------+
```

See:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html
- https://modern-sql.com/feature/values

Comment: OP wants time with time zone, i.e. CURRENT_TIME.

Comment: In standard SQL, the CURRENT_TIME and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP return values in the time zone of the current database session.

Comment: Yes, and CURRENT_TIME and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP include the time zone information. LOCALTIME and LOCALTIMESTAMP do not include the time zone information.